# Migrate KVM virtual machines on premises to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kvm-virtualization

I have a few virtual machines on KVM.
I think at least 2 ways:

1. Migrate everything KVM host with their virtual machines.
2. Migrate every Virtual Machine to AWS as an instance.

Is that feasible? Could be that process non-disrupting?

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/vm-import/

Answer (score 2):

Usually you would go for (2), since an EC2 instance is already a VM itself. It would also be much easier to manage later on.

Doing that without disruption might be possible, but I guess it'd be not that easy.

You might want to check out [AWS CloudEndure](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudendure-migration/), maybe that's helpful for your use case (haven't tried it by myself).